# Confidence of faces using the ML Kit in Android

Tags: android, face-detection, google-mlkit

I have an Android application which makes use of Google ML Kit for detecting faces over frames taken by CameraX. My application is really simple, and uses the snippet below.

```kotlin
override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
  detector.process(image)
    .addOnSuccessListener { faces ->
      ...
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
      ...
    }
    .addOnCompleteListener {
      ...
    }
}
```

I would need to collect all faces on that frame along with their **confidence** value, because I want to be sure the detection has a good accuracy.
According with the picture below, the `Face` object does not have any confidence value.

[face-object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipVtU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are right. there is no confidence score result exposed in API surface for FaceDetector. However, the face result is only returned if the confidence is >= 0.5 so it should be safe to use.